# Python: for loop inside print()

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, printing

I have a question about Python (3.3.2).

I have a list:

```
L = [['some'], ['lists'], ['here']]
```

I want to print these nested lists (each one on a new line) using the `print()` function:

```
print('The lists are:', for list in L: print(list, '\n'))
```

I know this is incorrect but I hope you get the idea. Could you please tell me if this is possible? If yes, how?

I know that I could do this:

```
for list in L:
    print(list)
```

However, I'd like to know if there are other options as well.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Apply the whole `L` object as separate arguments:

```
print('The lists are:', *L, sep='\n')
```

By setting `sep` to a newline this'll print all list objects on new lines.

Demo:

```
>>> L = [['some'], ['lists'], ['here']]
>>> print('The lists are:', *L, sep='\n')
The lists are:
['some']
['lists']
['here']
```

If you **have** to use a loop, do so in a list comprehension:

```
print('The lists are:', '\n'.join([str(lst) for lst in L]))
```

This'll omit the newline after `'The lists are:'`, you can always use `sep='\n'` here as well.

Demo:

```
>>> print('The lists are:', '\n'.join([str(lst) for lst in L]))
The lists are: ['some']
['lists']
['here']
>>> print('The lists are:', '\n'.join([str(lst) for lst in L]), sep='\n')
The lists are:
['some']
['lists']
['here']
```

Comment: Using `*L` is more efficient since it doesn't have to join the items into a new string. `print` just loops over the args, writing each to `stdout`.

Comment: Hey. Is there a way to do this in the new format? Something like print(f'{*L}')

Comment: @RaulChiarella: no, f-strings are not function calls and don't support call features like `*argument` expansion.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
>>> L = [['some'], ['lists'], ['here']]
>>> print("\n".join([str(x) for x in L]))
['some']
['lists']
['here']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

work for me:

```
L = [['some'], ['lists'], ['here']]
print("\n".join('%s'%item for item in L))
```

this one also work:

```
L = [['some'], ['lists'], ['here']]
print("\n".join(str(item) for item in L))
```

this one also:

```
L = [['some'], ['lists'], ['here']]
print("\n".join([str(item) for item in L]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looking for help in dict printing then here u go:

```
dictionary = {'test1':'value1', 'test1':'value1'}


print ('\n'.join(' : '.join(b for b in a) for a in dictionary.items()))
```

Comment: sorry, it should be 

print ('\n'.join(' : '.join(b for b in a) for a in dictionary.items()))

Answer (score 1):

Came late, but you can simply do

```
print("The lists are:", [list for list in L])
```

Comment: I can't do `print(i for i in range(10))`. What' wrong?

Comment: But I can print it as a list: `print([i for i in range(10)])`. Why not the first one??

Comment: This is because `i for i in range(10)` is not a correct syntax outside of brackets. ([check list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

You can have `foo = [i for i in range(10)]` because after seeing a bracket the compiler expect a for loop.

But ` foo = i for i in range(10)` doesn't work because it's like writing `foo = this does not work`

Answer (score 0):

The following will print the list. Each element on a new line, without quotes and brackets.

```py
print(*[item for i, item in enumerate(L)], sep='\n').
```

Comment: You are not using the index in `enumerate`. `print(*L, sep='\n')` would do the same.