# Is there a way to use the for loop within a print statement?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I'm a beginner, so please bear with me

I have the following code:

```
shapes = ['rect', 'rect', 'circle']
coords = ["34,44,210", "290,333,250", "337,300,44"]

for shape in shapes:
    for coord in coords:
        print(shape)
        print(coords)
```

I am very well aware that this prints it out multiple times, but I'm not able to find a way to avoid it.
A better way I would think, is to use it one-by-one inside the print statement, something like this:

```
print(shape for shape in shapes)
print(coord for coord in coords)
```

But this doesn't work, and only prints

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000282B2C69510>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000282B2C69510>
```

I'm not able to find a guide on printing the for loop inside the print statement.
I'm using this to be able to print something like:

```
id='rect' id2='34,44,210'
id='rect' id2='290,333,250'
id='circle' id2='337,300,44'
```

Is there a way? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I want to be able to print that exact thing.

Comment: What is your expected output ? Print the contents of the lists only once ?

Comment: As an intermediate step, you can try `print([shape for shape in shapes])`. That will not be exactly the same as your first example, but could help you understand the answer by Syed Ahmad in more depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a generator expression is already going in the right direction. However, it must be [*unpack*ed in the call](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) to get the items out of the generator into the `print`:

```
print(*(shape for shape in shapes))
```

This is a bit useless in this case, since the generator does not do anything useful – `print(*shapes)` works as well here.

As a more useful case, if you want to print all combinations of shapes and coords, a generator over both sequences can be used:

```
shapes = ['rect', 'rect', 'circle']
coords = ["34,44,210", "290,333,250", "337,300,44"]
print(*((shape, coord) for shape in shapes for coord in coords))
```

Python ships with various utilities that already implement common iteration patterns. For example, the combination of the two lists can be created via [`itertools.product(shapes, coords)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

What you likely need for such data is the *pairwise* folding of the two iterables. This is a common use-case and thus Python has a helper which is always available: [the builtin function `zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
>>> shapes = ['rect', 'rect', 'circle']
>>> coords = ["34,44,210", "290,333,250", "337,300,44"]
>>> # unpack pairs directly
>>> print(*zip(shapes, coords))
('rect', '34,44,210') ('rect', '290,333,250') ('circle', '337,300,44')
>>> #       v ----     format each pair     ---- v
>>> print(*(f"{shape}={coord}" for shape, coord in zip(shapes, coords)))
rect=34,44,210 rect=290,333,250 circle=337,300,44
>>> #       v ----     format each pair     ---- v                     v separate by newline
>>> print(*(f"{shape}={coord}" for shape, coord in zip(shapes, coords)), sep="\n")
rect=34,44,210
rect=290,333,250
circle=337,300,44
```

---

Keep in mind though that there is nothing wrong about using regular `for` loops. If the choice is between a single *newline-separated printing unpacked formatted zipped pairs* expression and several statements, use the more readable option.

```
for shape, coord in zip(shapes, coords):
    print(shape, '=', coord, sep='')
```

Comment: The pairwise folding of the two iterables works well, but they're enclosed in brackets, I wanted to use this to be able to print out something like
```
id='rect' id2='34,44,210'
```
and so on for the other two

Comment: @RedFox I've expanded the example with string formatting to get a `key=value` like output. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    print('The shapes are:', '\n'.join([shape for shape in shapes]))
    The lists are: 'rect'
    'rect'
    'circle'
```

Comment: see this thread for reference :- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774607/python-for-loop-inside-print)

Comment: The contents of ```shapes``` are already strings. No need to again convert them to strings.

Comment: You also don't need to create a list inside `join()`. `'\n'.join(shape for shape in shapes)` will do

Comment: But this puts it into a list, I just want to print them out without being in a list

Comment: I tried this but for me it didn't put your shapes in list

Comment: if you replace `'\n'` with `', '` everything would be in one row

Comment: yes if you want the all output in one row then please remove '\n'

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used here:

```
print(shape for shape in shapes)
```

is legal but it's a generator comprehension which is similar to list comp but returns a generator object.

Howerver, since your desired outputs are strings, you can join them with the newline escape pair `\n` and print the whole string once:

```
print("\n".join((i for i in shapes)))
```

Notice that the str casting is redundant since the element are strings already.